# Form submitted variable not retrieve data

Tags: php, html, mysql, fpdf

Though I couldn't find a solution for the issue on here, I thought to post this. When try to retrieve data from a form submitted variable `$receiptNo`, it doesn't work.

**sales.php**

```
<input name="txtReceiptNo" type="text" id="txtReceiptNo" size="10" value="<?php $receiptNo = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT max(sales_id)+1 FROM sales")); echo $receiptNo[0];?>" readonly />
```

**salesreceipt.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['txtReceiptNo'])){ $receiptNo = $_POST['txtReceiptNo']; } 

$result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT I.item_name, S.qty, S.unit_price, S.amount, S.date,S.receipt_no, S.discount, U.username 
FROM sales S
INNER JOIN items I ON S.item_id=I.item_id
INNER JOIN users U ON S.user_id=U.id
WHERE S.receipt_no=$receiptNo");
```

But, when tries to give database value for the `$receiptNo` as below, it retrieves the data.

```
$result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT I.item_name, S.qty, S.unit_price, S.amount, S.date,S.receipt_no, S.discount, U.username 
FROM sales S
INNER JOIN items I ON S.item_id=I.item_id
INNER JOIN users U ON S.user_id=U.id
WHERE S.receipt_no=324");
```

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

fpdf code snippet (`salesreceipt.php`):

```
<?php 

if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
  session_start(); 
} 

if(isset($_POST[$receiptNo])){ $receiptNo = $_POST['txtReceiptNo']; } 

$result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT I.item_name, S.qty, S.unit_price, S.amount, S.date,S.receipt_no, S.discount, U.username FROM sales S INNER JOIN items I ON S.item_id=I.item_id INNER JOIN users U ON S.user_id=U.id WHERE S.receipt_no='$receiptNo'"); $receipt_no = $row['receipt_no']; 

$pdf->Cell(45,5,$receipt_no,0,0,'L',0);

$pdf->Cell(40,10,$receiptNo,1);
```

[image]

Comment: Try `WHERE S.receipt_no='324'");` just in case the field type for `receipt_no` is a text type.;

Comment: It's `int` type. I added the screenshot now.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the variable is populated?

Comment: Sorry, how can I do it?

Comment: Place a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP page which receives the form submission. Fill out your form, submit and look closely at the data printed to the screen. Familiarize yourself with how form data is posted to scripts, including what gets passed and what doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @Jay, Yes it populates like below:

`'txtReceiptNo' => string '354' (length=3)`

Comment: What is the value in `$receiptNo` after the `if` statement?

Comment: `//get reciept number from session(sales page)
    if(isset($_POST[$receiptNo])){ $receiptNo = $_POST['txtReceiptNo']; } 

    var_dump($_POST);`

Hope this is correct. This code snippet is in `salesreceipt.php`, where as the form is in `sales.php`.


`if` statement resides in fpdf php page. As it opens as pdf, no output can see. How can I populate it on pdf?

Comment: `echo $receiptNo;`

Comment: No, I tried it before. It doesn't display.

Comment: You would populate it on the PDF as you would any other content. Is this whole question about FPDF?

Comment: Yes, this is the fpdf code snippet (`salesreceipt.php`):

`<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
       { 
           session_start(); 
       } 

if(isset($_POST[$receiptNo])){ $receiptNo = $_POST['txtReceiptNo']; }

$result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT I.item_name, S.qty, S.unit_price, S.amount, S.date,S.receipt_no, S.discount, U.username 
FROM sales S
INNER JOIN items I ON S.item_id=I.item_id
INNER JOIN users U ON S.user_id=U.id
WHERE S.receipt_no='$receiptNo'");

$receipt_no = $row['receipt_no'];

$pdf->Cell(45,5,$receipt_no,0,0,'L',0);`

Comment: Then do something like this `$pdf->Cell(40,10,$receiptNo,1);` to output the value to the page.

Comment: **Please do not dump code in comments**. It is hard to read. If you need to put additional information in your question click the 'edit' link and add to your question.

Comment: Remove the single quotes here `S.receipt_no=$receiptNo");` as I have done and try the query again. When you are querying an INT field you do not want to use quotes.

Comment: It displays nothing, I added the screenshot above.

Comment: Are there any errors in your error logs?

Comment: These are soon after `<?php` at the very begining of `sales.php` and `salesreceipt.php` page. 

`error_reporting(E_ALL );
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Appreciate your great help to overcome my issues, since I am a very newbie to programming. At the same time thank you very much for your kind help on this, learnt a lot.

Comment: Error appears as `"Notice: Undefined variable: receiptNo in.. "` for `if(isset($_POST['txtReceiptNo'])){ $receiptNo = $_POST['txtReceiptNo']; } `

Comment: If that is the case then `$_POST['txtReceiptNo']` is not set.

Comment: I tried different ways, but no luck since now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this.

There was not a `form` submission on calling the `PROCEED` button. There was just a `onclick` event to open a window, like below:

```
<input type="submit" name="btnPrintReceipt" id="btnPrintReceipt" value="PRINT &amp; PROCEED" onclick="window.open('<?php echo BASE_URL?>reports/salesreceipt2.php','popup','width=1200,height=900'); return false;"/>
```

I changed to this:

```
<input type="button" name="btnPrintReceipt" id="btnPrintReceipt" value="PRINT &amp; PROCEED" onclick="printProceed(true, txtReceiptNo.value);resetformTotal();"/>
```

and added an `ajax` call.

```
function printProceed(isPrint, recordId){

              var listCustomer = document.getElementById("listCustomer").value;
              var txtReceiptNo = document.getElementById("txtReceiptNo").value;
              var staff = document.getElementById("staff").value;
              var discount = document.getElementById("discount").value;
              var txtSubTotal = document.getElementById("txtSubTotal").value;
              var txtGrossTotal = document.getElementById("txtGrossTotal").value;

              // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
              var dataString = {listCustomer: listCustomer, txtReceiptNo: txtReceiptNo, staff: staff, discount: discount};
              if (listCustomer == ''|| txtReceiptNo == ''|| staff == ''|| discount == '') {
              salesitemsAddFail();
              } 
              else {

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/pms/includes/functions/sales_functions.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       //includes/functions/sales_functions.php
       success:function(html){
            if(isPrint == true){
            printpdf(recordId,txtSubTotal,txtGrossTotal,discount);
        }
       }

                         //reload the sales datagrid once add the item details to temporary table (sales_temp)
                 //window.location.reload();
                 //refresh/update the sub total value when adding

       });

                  $('#list').trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);
                  $("#sub_total_div").load(location.href + " #sub_total_div");

}}
```